# Dynamic lib(rary) in Eclipse for NON-Dynamic Web Projects

Tags: eclipse, dynamic, jar

Is there a way to add a dynamic library folder to a plain Java project similar to WEB-INF/lib in a Dynamic Web Project?

I mean, can I specify a simple folder, let's just call it lib, and have Eclipse monitor it for any library jars I might want to add or remove.

Currently I only know this behaviour from the Web App Libraries where any jar you copy into WebContent/WEB-INF/lib is automatically added to the class path, but in "regular" Java Projects I need to add every jar by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  It requires writing a suitable extension to the org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathContainerInitializer.  If you're in the Package Explorer, though, you can just select all the jars within the View and use the context menu to add/remove them to/from the Java Build Path.